# Can i search my google contacts by phone number

Tags: google-contacts

sort of - if i come across a number and want to know if it belongs to any of my contacts i want to be able to enter the number in my contact page and hit search. the search will look at the numbers attached to my contacts and it returns the contacts that match the partial phone number i am searching for.

will this be cool or what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Better Search in Google Contacts](http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2009/02/better-search-in-google-contacts.html):

> One of the most significant limitation
>   of Google's contact manager was that
>   most of the contact fields weren't
>   searchable. This problem has been
>   addressed and you can now search for
>   any information included, from titles
>   and companies, to locations and **phone numbers**.

Comment: It better worked. In 2017 this feature isn't there anymore.

Comment: by the end of 2019 dec, I still am unable to search my google contacts by number